# phpmyadmin / mysqli on docker do not connect

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi, phpmyadmin

I want to run two docker container, one for phpmyadmin and one for mysql server, so i wrote this docker-compose file to run it on RaspberryPi:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

The volume mount, the containers build up, the phpmyadmin page load but when i try to login with server: machine-ip:3306, user: root, pass: test; got this error:

```
mysqli::real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=34
```

```
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away
```

Tried everything and worked only one time, but when i restarted it not worked again

Comment: I did: `docker run --name phpmyadmin -d -e PMA_HOST=ip-address-ofMysql-server -p 8082:80 phpmyadmin`, after this I was able to login using phpmyadmin at: `http://localhost:8082`.   I do not see why you need a volume mount ?

Comment: I understood that mysql take about 20-30 min to start the server, and until that i can't log in, maybe is due to raspberrypi speed.
I mounted a volume (that now don't work) to store db data

Comment: MySQL server is more than a mounted volume that contains some data....

Comment: What do you mean?